# List all the users in the Active Directory Group

Tags: java, ldap

I am facing some difficulties while listing all the users in the Active Directory. I reached to the group, but unfortunately, I could not retrieve all the users. I am looking for the user Full Names, usernames, directorate. My code is:

```
package client;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.*;   
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.directory.*; 

public class AD1 {
    public AD1() {
        super();
    }

    public static String usersContainer = "cn=XX,ou=XX,ou=Groups,dc=XX,dc=XX,dc=XXX";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            LdapContext ctx = null;
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
            //it can be <domain\\userid> something that you use for windows login
            //it can also be
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
            // env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
            try {
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password".getBytes("UTF8"));
            }
            catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) { /* ignore */ }

            //in following property we specify ldap protocol and connection url.
            //generally the port is 389
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://IP:PORT");

            ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

            System.out.println("Connection Successful.");

            DirContext ctx1 = new InitialDirContext(env);   
            SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();        
            String[] attrIDs = { "distinguishedName","cn","name","uid",
                                 "sn",
                                 "givenname",
                                 "memberOf",
                                 "samaccountname",
                                 "userPrincipalName" };

            ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);       
            ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE); 
            //ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);
            NamingEnumeration answer = ctx1.search( usersContainer, "(objectClass=user)", ctls );     

            System.out.print("Out while loop");
            while(answer.hasMore()) {
                System.out.print("while loop11");
                SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult)answer.next();          
                Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();           
                System.out.println(attrs.get("uid"));         
                ctx1.close(); 
            }

        } catch(NamingException nex) {
            System.out.println("Active Directory Connection: FAILED");
            nex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: You shouldn't be closing the context inside the `answer.hasMore()` loop. The rest of it seems to be just a formatting problem. You're only printing the `uid` so that's all you see.

Answer (score 2):

As it's active directory and not real ldap your talking about, can you help us with more details about ldap/active directory configuration ?
It's kind hard to help you with informations you give

***Edit 1:***
your problem is here no ?

```
while(answer.hasMore()) {
     System.out.print("while loop11");
     SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult)answer.next();          
     Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();           
     //System.out.println(attrs.get("uid"));
     System.out.println(attrs.get("cn"));
     ctx1.close(); 
     }
```

Comment: In fact, I am not getting an error. I am getting a result which is : CN=KIM KIM,OU=XX,OU=Director,OU=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX, CN=Johny John,OU=XX,OU=Accounts,OU=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX. I want to retreive only the CN for each one and the OU which has the directorates. Currently there are in one line.

Comment: I tried to do the code which you have provided, and it showed me the group Name. There is only one field in this group which is member and it will give me the previous line.

Comment: it's strange, you should try a debug with a breakpoint in you while loop and watch carefully what you get in attrs, because as you look for users object, you should access to more than a simple dn or cn.take a look to all the attribute, I can't help you more than that. Sorry